# OpsHub and Requirement to Map 100% of TFS Users - Cannot satisfy the requirement

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

There are users that are no longer with the company [no ActiveDirectory Account BUT a user in TFS] and they belong to Projects that I have NO INTENTION of migrating to VSO {legacy Projects}.  I’m not going to Delete them from TFS in order to eliminate the User from the Mapping Requirement check in OpsHub Tool.
I’ve selected a specific Project to Migrate. I’ve mapped all users for that Project I’m attempting to Migrate yet the Tool is blocking me from proceeding because 100% of the users in TFS DefaultCollection aren’t mapped.

Is there a backdoor? I don't believe I'm going to be able to satisfy the requirement but need to be able to proceed.

Comment: One approach we used internally was to map former developers to the Account Service.  We were okay with that and the comments are appended with the original information so that we have it available in the history.

Answer (score 0):

If names (based on the full name) are found in both on-premise TFS and VSO, it will automatically match them. However, for these names with different full name, you have to matches them manually.

As the screenshot shows, you need to select users from both systems, and click arrow to map them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain, the additional users in question have not done **ANY** change in the projects that you are looking to migrate, you can safely bulk map them to **ANY** user of VSO.

The only offside, if by chance there happens to be some change done by them. In VSO, it will appear as if it was done by the VSO user they were mapped to (in the above step).

Mapping of all existing users is required in the tool because of the same obvious reason.

*If user X of source tfs has done an activity, the tool requires to know which user Y of vso should do it (ie. impersonate it)*

Now since, going through all the items/data of TFS to see, if a particular user did any activity or not, does not make sense.  Having an exclusive mapping takes care of that.

Hope this answers your question.